# jQuery mobile pagecontain show not firing

Tags: jquery, mobile

I'm using the following code but the alert is not firing when the page is changed.

```
function goToHome(){
    $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', 'index.html', {
            show: function( event, ui ) { 
                alert('test') 
            },
            transition: 'slide',
            changeHash: true,
            reverse: false,
            showLoadMsg: true,
            reload: false
        });
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: you have the event wrapped in a function.  try moving it to document.ready()?

Comment: document.ready() will only fire on a page refresh, but pagecontainer change doesn't refresh the page, it just changes the content to the url specified.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see, it looks like there is no 'show' option in the change event.  You bind the show event when you initialize the pagecontainer. http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-show

```
$(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer({
  show: function( event, ui ) {}
});

$(':mobile-pagecontainer').on( "pagecontainershow", function( event, ui ) {
    alert('test');
} );

function goToHome(){
    $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', 'index.html', {
            transition: 'slide',
            changeHash: true,
            reverse: false,
            showLoadMsg: true,
            reload: false
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but still no luck with that. Plus I only want the show event when it loads the home page.